# angular 2 material input default focus remove

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular-material

I have one dialog with one text input , some radio buttons and ok cancel. When the dialog open the cursor is blinking inside the text input which means the placeholder text has zoomed out and hard to read. placeholder text is something like 'Describe details of the issue in this box'. How can I remove default autofocus in angular 2 ? As a hack even if I can somehow make the placeholder not zoom out I am good. Please advise. Using angular material controls.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Another solution is setting the dialog's inputs' tabindex to -1.

```
<button tabindex="-1" #closeAuthPanelButton mat-icon-button>
  <mat-icon (click)="emitAuthPanelClose()">close</mat-icon>
</button>
```

Answer (score 10):

In the config object you pass after the component in `dialog.open()` you can set the `autofocus` property to `false`.

```
this.dialog.open(SomeComponent, {
  width: '100px',
  data: {},
  autoFocus: false
})
```

Comment: Not working. No errors. Will try and create a stackbtlitz.

Comment: @Gullu Just adding `autoFocus: false` as given above worked fine for opened dialog.